# Find intersect of different dictionary values variable

Tags: c#, dictionary, set-intersection

I have one Dictionary declared as type

```
var dictionary1 = Dictionary<string, Type1>
```

and another as

```
var dictionary2 = Dictionary<string, Type2>
```

Each dictionary value type has a public variable called `classid` so:

```
dictionary1["key"].classid = 100
```

is also in:

```
dictionary2["key"].classid = 100
```

I know they are of different types, but is there an inbuilt way to find the intersections of just these two private variables and possibly return me a dictionary of that single type? So if the classid were equivalent I could get an intersected dictionary of Type Dictionary1?

Comment: Why is `classid` private if you need to use it outside the class?

Comment: Wait, If `classid` is private `dictionary1["key"].classid = 100;` won't compile.

Comment: Was not meant to be private my mistake.

Comment: So you want all elements of `dictionary1` where the `classid` of the value is also found in the values of `dictionary2`? To the keys have to match? Not exactly clear IMHO. Maybe you should give some example input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant query, but it should do the trick:

```
var intersection = dictionary1
.Where(kvp1 => 
   dictionary2.ContainsKey(kvp1.Key) 
   && dictionary2[kvp1.Key].classid = kvp1.Value.classid)
.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

This should fetch all key-value pairs in dictionary1 whose keys also exist in dictionary2, and whose classid matches the dictionary2 object's classid. Those key-value pairs are then transformed into a new dictionary.

Comment: @user2281557 Glad to hear. If this has helped you, don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted using the checkmark-icon to the left.

Comment: You could also use `TryGetValue` rather than `ContainsKey(key)` followed by a `dictionary[key]` lookup: one lookup per iteration should be quicker than two.

Comment: @LukeH That's true, but until C# 6 comes around with the ability to declare variables as part of an `out` method call, this would require breaking the lambda expression into a full-scale {}-covered block scope, which is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [`Where`/`ContainsKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673530/142637), you could also use a simple `join`, which is more readable and (probably) faster for larger sets of data:

```
var result = from kv1 in dictionary1
             join kv2 in dictionary2 on 
                new {kv1.Key, kv1.Value.classid} equals 
                new {kv2.Key, kv2.Value.classid}
             select kv1;

var new_dict = result.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below mentioned code

```
        Dictionary<int, string> t = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Dictionary<int, string> t1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        t.Add(100, "f");
        t1.Add(100, "f2");

        var abc=t.Where(p=>t1.Any(q=>q.Key==p.Key));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but dictionaries may not be what you want and this question may be a duplicate phrased differently:

[C# Linq intersect/except with one part of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633375/c-sharp-linq-intersect-except-with-one-part-of-object)

BTW the property you want to use for the intersection should be public.