# Compare 2 List using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 list which contains close to *500k+* records. `List <Animal> and List <Zoo>.`

The Model

**Animal**

```
Id
BllodType
ZooId
```

**Zoo**

```
Z_ID
ZooName
ZooAdress
```

I need to write a LINQ function where it could return a List of `Animals` that matches the `ZooId` (`Z_Id`).

What I tried to do :

```
List<Animal> matchingAni= allZooList.Any(x => allAnimalList.Contains(x));
```

It says

> Cannot convert from Animal to Zoo.

Note: Since, I have *500k+* records in these Lists, I am looking for a optimized way to traverse these list in lesser time.

Comment: You’lk want to do a `Join`.

Comment: Why do you need this in the first place? Since you are using Entity-Framework - your `Zoo` object should have a `Navigation Property` called `Animals` which should return you what you want, namly all `Animals` for that `Zoo`?!?

Comment: Are there any inheritance between animal and zoo ?

Comment: Look at also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10633506/8090964

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are getting that error because `allAnimalList` is a list of `Animal`, while `x` (in the LINQ selector) is of type `Zoo`. Therefore when you do `allAnimalList.Contains(x)`, you are trying to see if an `Animal` list contains a `Zoo`, which produces the error: `Cannot convert from Animal to Zoo.`

Try this:

```
// Use a hashset to make .Contains() an O(1) operation
var zooIDs = new HashSet<int>(from zoo in allZooList select zoo.Z_ID);
List<Animal> matchingAnimal = allAnimalList.Where(animal => zooIDs.Contains(animal.ZooID)).ToList();
```

To use a LINQ JOIN:

```
var matchingAnimal = from animal in allAnimalList 
                     join zoo in allZooList 
                     on animal.ZooID equals zoo.Z_ID
                     select animal
```

Comment: How can I do this with a JOIN ?

Comment: `ConvertAll` already returns a List, calling `.ToList()` isn't necessary.

Comment: A little warning about performance, since OP mentions his list has 500k+ entries, you should consider using a `HashSet` for your `.Contains` approach. Calling 500k+ times `Contains` on a 500k+ `List` will be very very slow.

Comment: @RandRandom thank you for your comments, I agree with you hash set approach

Comment: In terms if performance what you suggest ? Should I go with the HashSet approach or the Join ?

Comment: @Illep If these lists are already in memory (I assume they are, given your example), I would suggest using the first method. If these records are stored in a database, and you are retrieving them, then I would prefer the second method as LINQ/SQL will optimize the query.